# Trigger with Ids other than OLD.id

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-delete

I have a table like this:

**user_oauth**:

```
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id        | int(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| google_id      | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| facebook_id    | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| windowslive_id | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

which contains id of 3 the tables `user_facebook`, `user_google`, `user_windowslive`,

Example for **user_facebook**:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | varchar(30)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| email     | varchar(60)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| firstname | varchar(30)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname  | varchar(30)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| link      | varchar(100)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| locale    | varchar(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| picture   | varchar(200)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| verified  | int(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I would like to make a TRIGGER ON DELETE on `user_oauth`, which will delete `user_facebook` row if `facebook_id` of `user_oauth` is filled.

So I tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_oauth_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `user_oauth` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM user_facebook
    WHERE user_facebook.id = user_oauth.facebook_id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I have the error message:
`Unknown column 'user_oauth.facebook_id' in 'where clause'`

How to do it?
Thanks.

**Solution**

I had misunderstanding the `OLD` statement, so I had to:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_oauth_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `user_oauth` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM user_facebook
    WHERE user_facebook.id = OLD.facebook_id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this with triggers.  Do this with cascading delete constraints.

```
alter table oath
    add constraint fk_oath_facebook
        foreign key (facebookid) references user_facebook(id)
        on delete cascade;
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) does a pretty good job of explaining constraints and the cascading capabilities.

Comment: I can't use foreign keys because my storage engine is `MyISAM` and not `InnoDB` and I need `MyISAM` for some `FULLTEXT indexes` which is not supported by `InnoDB`.

Comment: @LondonSmith . . . InnoDB supports full text since MySQL 5.6.  You might consider upgrading to a newer version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what have been suggested, you can as well consider wrapping both the DML statement inside a transaction block in a stored procedure and pass the `facebook_id` as parameter to the procedure. Such that both operation will happen in same order. Something like

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `transaction_sp` (@facebook_id varchar(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
    -- ERROR
  ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
 BEGIN
    -- WARNING
 ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM user_facebook WHERE id = @facebook_id;
DELETE FROM `user_oauth` WHERE facebook_id = @facebook_id;
COMMIT;
END
$$
```

Comment: I am new with TRIGGERS It's my second one and your solution is a bit complex for me. I have edited my question with the solution, I had misunderstanding the `OLD` statement and how to use it. Thanks